# how do i change a css property after a time interval of 3 seconds using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, settimeout

this is the javascript code i've been using.
and i keep getting the error

```
    '''
    cannot set property 'animationplaystate' of undefined.
    '''

    '''
    window.setTimeout(function time(){
      var run=document.getElementsByClassName('logo');
      run.style.animationplaystate='paused';
     }, 3000);
    '''
```

below is the style of the element

```
'''
.logo{
color: rgb(0, 158, 150);
float:right;
padding-right:0px;
font-weight: 600;
padding-top:5px;
margin-right: 20px;
font-size: 2em;
padding-left: 30px;
animation-name:logo;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-play-state: running; 
}

'''
```

Comment: is this code below the tag or above the tag ? reason I am asking your code is running before the tag is actually rendered, use jQuery document ready event and set the CSS

Comment: those are two seperate code in a seperate file

Comment: that doesn't matter, if you include `<script>` tag at the end of the `<body>` tag then it will be last rendered, also if you jQuery it will trigger a function when the full document is ready to be programmed

Comment: anyway, I gave the answer below, I hope it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
run.style['animation-play-state'] = 'paused';
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> The `getElementsByClassName` method of Document interface returns an `array-like object` of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s)

so techniclly `getElementsByClassName` always return an array
You need use array index to access the elements
Also the style attribute is camel case `animationPlayState`
in your code all are in small letters

Try this code

```
run[0].style.animationPlayState = 'paused'
```

To start animation and stop animation purely using CSS you can try

```
.logo {
  animation-play-state: paused; 
}

.logo:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

so, for your case, you don't even need javascript

Comment: can you give me the html tag I will create a jsfiddle

Comment: come to chat -- chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: i know that it returns an array ,but here there is only one element inside that class name ....well we'd assume that it's gonna take it as a single element by default.

Comment: that is why I put zero `run[0]` , does it throw error for undefined ?

Comment: in google chrome console you can directly type javascript to check that particular element is coming or not

Comment: I can invite you let me do it

Comment: come to this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Comment: ok i have this logo that appears from above on loading the page within a time frame of 2s, and i want the logo to transform 360deg in x-axis when the cursor hovers above the logo and it works fine but as soon as the cursor moves away from the logo ...... the logo seems to animate from above again . i don't want this .

Comment: i don't have enough reputations on stackoverflow.

Comment: ok, I understood, you can use :hover CSS to set animation, so normal `.logo` should not be linked with animation

Comment: use this example https://codepen.io/valhead/pen/rfump, start animation on hover which is `animation-play-state: running;` which will work, in the normal css class set `animation-play-state: paused; `

Comment: to whom where ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know:

The DOM is not ready yet for the browser API to tell JavaScript more. Window setTimeout is executed before DOM is ready (before window.onload).

You are facing this p.b:
[Javascript document.getElementsByClassName returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235127/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-returning-undefined)

my answer is to wrap in window.load (or document.ready):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() 
{
    // code here
});
```

Consider document ready too. 
[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)